# Proving Segal's Category $\Gamma \simeq \mathbf{FinSet}_*^{op}$

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to show that Segal's category $\Gamma$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{FinSet}_*^{op}$, the opposite of the category of finite pointed sets with basepoint preserving morphisms.  I'm intuitively gathering that $\Gamma$ can be shown to be the skeleton of $\mathbf{FinSet}_*^{op}$, or equivalently that $\Gamma^{op}$ is the skeleton of $\mathbf{FinSet}_*$, but I'm having trouble just understanding what the opposites of these categories are.

For reference $\Gamma$ is the category consisting of finite sets, and morphisms from $S$ to $T$ are maps $\theta:S \to P(T)$ where $P(T)$ is the power set of $T$, such that distinct points in $S$ get mapped to disjoint subsets of $T$.  If $\theta:S\to P(T)$ and $\varphi:T \to P(U)$ are two such morphisms, then their composite is given by a morphism $\psi: S \to P(U)$ such that

$$
\psi(\alpha) \;\; =\;\; \bigcup_{\beta \in \theta(\alpha)} \varphi(\beta).
$$

My biggest issue here is that I can't even conceive of the opposite morphisms.  How can these be found?  If I wanted to demonstrate $\Gamma^{op} \simeq \mathbf{FinSet}_*$ and then use duality, I'd have to find the opposite morphisms $\theta^{op}$, but would these be mappings from $P(T)$ to $S$, or from $T$ to $P(S)$?  What's even the form of the identity morphisms in $\Gamma$?  I thought possibly these would be the mappings $1_S:S\to P(S)$ such that $1_S(\alpha) = \{\alpha\}$.  In what sense can $1_S$ be seen as an isomorphism in $\Gamma$?

In what sense could we naturally find a notion of "opposite" here?  For instance, for $A \in P(T)$ I'm doubtful we could define $\theta^{op}(A) = \theta^{-1}(A)$ since $\theta$ was a set-valued function to begin with.  Either way, there's no guarantee that $A\in P(T)$ would be in the image of $\theta$.

Comment: Don't think about finding concrete functions as morphisms of $\Gamma^\mathrm{op}$.  Instead, find a contravariant equivalence from $\Gamma$ to based finite sets.

Comment: @Randall Suggestion duly noted.  I'm (clearly) very new to category theory.  Is it common practice to conceive of opposites via contravariant functors rather than finding them concretely?  This concept is one that I've had trouble understanding in general.  I think too I'm struggling with the idea of skeleta.  I've read that $\Gamma$ is the skeleton of $\mathbf{FinSet}_*^{op}$.  What constitutes an isomorphism in $\Gamma$?

Comment: I don't think sketeta have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your typical morphism from $S$ to $T$ is a map $S\to\wp(T)$ satisfying the condition
you list. This induces a map $\phi$
from $T_*$ to $S_*$ as follows, where $S_*$ is the disjoint
union of $S$ and a basepoint $*$.

This map $\phi$ is defined by $\phi(t)=s$ whenever $t\in\theta(s)$ for some
$s$ (necessarily unique as the $\theta(s)$ are disjoint, and $\phi(t)=*$ if
$t=*$ or $t$ is not in any of the $\theta(s)$.

Then $S\mapsto S_*$ and $\theta\mapsto\phi$ are the object and morphism maps of
the required contravariant functor.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.  I did want to reiterate my question that I had in the comments above: is it generally common practice to conceive of opposites via contravariant functors rather than finding them concretely?  In other words, is there a closed-form way to write the morphisms $\Gamma^{op}$ or $\mathbf{FinSet}_*^{op}$ rather than finding an appropriate contravariant functor $F$ and concluding them equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s best to understand the equivalence $Γ ≃ \mathbf{FinSet}_*^{\mathrm{op}}$ via
$$
  Γ ≅ \mathbf{FinSet}_∂^{\mathrm{op}} ≃ \mathbf{FinSet}_*^{\mathrm{op}} \,,
$$
where the intermediary term $\mathbf{FinSet}_∂$ is the category of finite sets and partially defined functions.

#### Partially defined functions

Recall that a *partially defined function*, or simply *partial function*, from a set $S$ to a set $T$ is a pair $(D, f)$ consisting of a subset $D$ of $S$ (the domain of the partial function) and a function $f \colon D \to T$.
The composite of two partial functions $(D, f) \colon S \to T$ and $(E, g) \colon T \to U$ is the partial function $(F, h)$ with $F = D ∩ f^{-1}(E)$ and $h(s) = g(f(s))$ for every $s ∈ F$.
This gives us a category $\mathbf{Set}_∂$ of sets and partial functions between them.
We have a full subcategory $\mathbf{FinSet}_∂$ of $\mathbf{Set}_∂$ whose objects are the finite sets.

#### The isomorphism $Γ ≅ \mathbf{FinSet}_∂^{\mathrm{op}}$

If $(D, f)$ is a partial function from a set $S$ to a set $T$, then we can consider for every element $t$ of $T$ its fibre $f^{-1}(t)$.
We get in this way a map $θ \colon T \to P(S)$ given by $θ(t) = f^{-1}(t)$ for every $t ∈ T$, and the sets $θ(t)$ and $θ(t')$ are disjoint for every two distinct element $t$ and $t'$ of $T$.

Conversely, if $θ \colon T \to P(S)$ is a map such that the sets $θ(t)$ and $θ(t')$ are disjoint for any two distinct elements $t$ and $t'$ of $T$, then we get a corresponding partial function $(D, f)$ from $S$ to $T$ with domain $D = \bigcup_{t ∈ T} θ(t)$ and mapping $f$ given by $f(s) = t$ for every $t ∈ T$ and every $s ∈ θ(t)$.

The above two constructions are mutually inverse, and result in an isomorphism (and not just an equivalence) of categories between $Γ$ and $\mathrm{FinSet}_∂^{\mathrm{op}}$.

#### The equivalences $\mathbf{Set}_∂ ≃ \mathbf{Set}_*$ and $\mathbf{FinSet}_∂ ≃ \mathbf{FinSet}_*$

Every partial function can be extended to a total function.
To every set $S$ we add a new value named $\mathtt{undefined}$, resulting in a set $S_*$.
Every partial function $(D, f) \colon S \to T$ can then extended to the total function
$$
  S_* \longrightarrow T_* \,,
  \quad
  s
  \longmapsto
  \begin{cases}
    f(s)               & \text{if $s ∈ D$,} \\
    \mathtt{undefined} & \text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$
This extension maps $\mathtt{undefined}$ in $S_*$ to $\mathtt{undefined}$ in $T_*$, and we get overall a functor $F \colon \mathbf{Set}_∂ \to \mathbf{Set}_*$.

We have similarly a functor $G \colon \mathbf{Set}_* \to \mathbf{Set}_∂$ that removes from every pointed set $(S, s_0)$ its base-point $s_0$, resulting in the set $S ∖ \{ s_0 \}$, while restricting every pointed function $f \colon (S, s_0) \to (T, t_0)$ to a partial function $S ∖ \{s_0\} \to T ∖ \{ t_0 \}$ with domain $S ∖ f^{-1}(t_0)$.

The composite $G ∘ F$ is the identity functor on $\mathsf{Set}_*$.
The composite $F ∘ G$ only renames the base point and is therefore still isomorphic to the identity functor on $\mathbf{Set}_*$ (the pointed set $(S, s_0)$ is mapped to the pointed set $(S ∖ \{s_0\} ∪ \{\mathtt{undefined}\}, \mathtt{undefined})$, which is not set-theoretically equal to $(S, s_0)$ but still isomorphic to it.)

We have a (fairly explicit) equivalence of categories
$$
  \mathbf{Set}_∂ ≃ \mathbf{Set}_* \,.
$$
By restriction, we have also an equivalence of categories
$$
  \mathbf{FinSet}_∂ ≃ \mathbf{FinSet}_* \,.
$$